# Windows batch file check time and date then rename

Tags: date, batch-file, time, file-rename

I need to rename todays date `paymentpagecalls20200128.txt` and `WithdrawalConfirm20200128.txt` to `paymentpagecalls20200129_*time*.txt`and  `WithdrawalConfirm20200129_*time*.txt` when it is every 8 hours or if possible 12:00am/6:00am/10:00PM.

I have this code to get my time ( just copied it to some of my searched )

```
set "destination=C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback_UP\Destination"
set day=0
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "result=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"
echo %result%
for /r "C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\For Rename" %%G in (*%result%.txt) do (
ren "%%~fG" "C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\For Rename"
if exist "C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\For Rename%%~nxG" (
    echo File "%%~fG" renamed successfully.
    ) else (
    echo File "%%~fG" renamed failed.
   )
)
pause
```

how can I insert the part to check the time then rename it?

Comment: Will an c# exe do or bat is a must ?

Comment: Bat file would be great but c# will be so appreciated @Clint

Comment: I am also thinking that it might be easier to c# but honestly I done have dept knowledge in both.

Comment: You're only doing a rename of one or more files using a known glob/pattern, and as the majority of your script is already vbscript, you would be better advised to use vbscript for it all. Please also note that this site is not here to add additional code to your working code, its purpose is to help you to fix an issue with your existing code. Technically your question is off topic and you should be more than grateful should somebody be willing to help you before the topic is closed. The expectation is trhat you attempt to code the additional requirements yourself, before requesting assistance.

Comment: Ok, you want to rename your file to current date every day at X Time, have I understood correctly?

Comment: @Clint I have to rename my paymentpagecalls*datetoday*.txt to paymentpagecalls*datetoday*_*time*.txt where time is if possible 12:00am/6:00am/10:00PM so in 1 day there will be 3 times of renaming

Comment: Use this link and start a chat with me https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4686729/clint

Comment: @Clint unfortunately I dont have enough reputation I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Break down of what's happening

- Retreive all .txt files from said directory that match given criteria
- We parse the filenames and extract the existing date and append the new date
- Rename the file(s)

> The output of this which is an ".exe" can be scheduled in task
>   scheduler to executed at given interval based on given condition.
>
> ***Go to TaskScheduler > Action > Create Basic Task > Set Trigger, Action > Finish***

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;


    namespace Test
    {

      public class Program
      {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FolderPath = @"C:\Users\John\Documents";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);

            var files = di.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")
           .Where(s => s.Name.Contains("Withdrawal")
            || s.Name.Contains("payment")).ToList();

            var Currentfile1 = files[0].FullName;
            var Currentfile2 = files[1].FullName;

            //Parsing files
            var Newfile1 = Currentfile1.Substring(0, Currentfile1.Length - 2);
            var Newfile2 = Currentfile2.Substring(0, Currentfile2.Length - 2);

            // Append new date
             Newfile1 = Newfile1 + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt";
             Newfile2 = Newfile2 + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt";

            //Rename
            File.Move(Currentfile1, Newfile1);
            File.Move(Currentfile2, Newfile2);


        }  
    }
}
```